# how can i use spellchecking in django (haystack with whoosh)?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am working on a django website. I want to search from a lots of texts from django.models(texts is something like stackoverflow questions). I am doing search with Haystack+whoosh. It is very nice using it. Much better than `django.object.filter(body_text__icontains="food")`

So i would like to know whether i able to have Spelling Suggestions using **whoosh** or **some other PUre python package available**. i don't like solr(since it needs java, after every update i need to rebuild the index using java(solr))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Whoosh's documentation for version 2.4.1](http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/index.html) indicates it does indeed have a pure-Python [spelling suggestion module](http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/spelling.html).